# Can someone look at this php file and see if they can spot an issue. I'm stumped

Tags: php

My main website references this php file at the beginning of the document like this

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('func.php');
?>
```

db.php is a database reference file and it works fine.  However, as soon as I reference func.php the website has the following error:

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

So I would love if you would look at the following code and see if you can spot mistakes that would make this happen.  Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
require_once('models.php');
require_once('phpspellcheck/include.js');
$spellcheckObject = new PHPSpellCheck();
$spellcheckObject -> LicenceKey = "TRIAL";
$spellcheckObject -> DictionaryPath = ("phpspellcheck/dictionaries/");
$spellcheckObject -> LoadDictionary("English (International)") ;
$spellcheckObject -> LoadCustomDictionary("custom.txt");

$ckfile = tempnam('/tmp', 'ADCOOK');

//**************************************
//     Page load dropdown results     //
//**************************************
function getTierOne()
{
    /*$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT vmake FROM vmake") 
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['vmake'].'">'.$tier['vmake'].'</option>';
        }*/

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if(isset($_GET['func']) && $_GET['func'] == "vmake") { 
   vmake($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function vmake($drop_var)
{  
    /*include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vmake WHERE vmake='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '
          <option style="width:242" value=" " selected="selected">Model</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option style="width:242" value="'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'">'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'</option>';
            }

*/

}


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // Keep count
    $count = 0;

    // Time to process searches!

    // Is it a familiar zip code?
    if(substr($_POST['zip'], 0, 2) == '45') {
        if($_POST['homesearch'] == true) {
            $count = craigs('http://ogden.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['city'] . ' ' . $_POST['propertytype'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        } elseif($_POST['carsearch'] == true) {
            $count = craigs('http://ogden.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['vmake'] . ' ' . $_POST['vmodel'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        } else {
            $count = craigs('http://ogden.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['item'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        }
    } elseif(substr($_POST['zip'], 0, 2) == '65') {
        if($_POST['homesearch'] == true) {
            $count = craigs('http://boise.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['city'] . ' ' . $_POST['propertytype'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        } elseif($_POST['carsearch'] == true) {
            $count = craigs('http://boise.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['vmake'] . ' ' . $_POST['vmodel'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        } else {
            $count = craigs('http://boise.craigslist.org/search/sss', $_POST['item'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
        }
    }
    // Okay, it's neither.
    // Is it a home search?
    elseif(isset($_POST['homesearch']) && $_POST['homesearch'] == true) {
        // First off, let's split up the cities.
        $cities = explode(',', $_POST['city']);

        // Now, let's translate our owner types.
        if($_POST['homeseller'] == 'owner') {
            $homeseller = '1';
        } elseif($_POST['homeseller'] == 'agent') {
            $homeseller = '0';
        } else {
            $homeseller = '';
        }

        // Now, let's translate our apartment types.
        if($_POST['propertytype'] == '') {
            $propertytype = 0;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'apartment') {
            $propertytype = 3;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'singlefamily') {
            $propertytype = 1;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'townhome') {
            $propertytype = 2;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'manufactured') {
            $propertytype = 4;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'horse') {
            $propertytype = 5;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'vacation') {
            $propertytype = 6;
        } elseif($_POST['propertytype'] == 'multi') {
            $propertytype = 7;
        } else {
            $propertytype = '';
        }

        //function house($item = null, $type = 0, $city = null, $state = null, $zip = null, $distance = null, $seller = null, $pricemin = null, $pricemax = null, $minsqft = null, $maxsqft = null, $minacres = null, $maxacres = null, $minbed = null)
        foreach($cities as $city) {
            $count = house($_POST['item'], $propertytype, $_POST['city'], $_POST['state'], $_POST['zip'], $_POST['distance'], $homeseller, $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax'], $_POST['minsqfeet'], $_POST['maxsqfeet'], $_POST['minacres'], $_POST['maxacres'], $_POST['minbedrooms']);
        }
    } elseif(isset($_POST['carsearch']) && $_POST['carsearch'] == true) {
        //function car($pricemin, $pricemax, $vmake, $vmodel, $minmileage, $maxmileage, $year, $carseller, $doors)
        $count = car($_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax'], $_POST['vmake'], $_POST['vmodel'], $_POST['minmileage'], $_POST['maxmileage'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['carseller'], $_POST['doors']);
    } else {
        $count = ksl($_POST['item'], $_POST['zip'], $_POST['distance'], $_POST['pricemin'], $_POST['pricemax']);
    }

    $perDay = round($count/7);

    if ($count > 14) {
        echo "<p>Based on your search criteria, we estimate that you will receive approximately $perDay alerts a day.</p><p>If this is ok, just press SUBMIT. If not, please press edit and be more specific in your search criteria.</p><p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"doSubmit()\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"$('.loading').dialog('destroy')\" /></p>";
    } elseif ($count > 0) {
        doSubmit();
    } else {
        $bad = false;
        $words = explode(" ", $_POST['item']) {
        if(count($words) > 0) {
            foreach($words as $word) {
                if(!$spellcheckObject->SpellCheckWord($word)) { $bad = true; }
            }
        }
        if($bad) {
            echo "<p>Current estimates show no results based on your current criteria.</p><p>Please ensure the all details are accurate before proceeding.</p><p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"doSubmit()\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"$('.loading').dialog('destroy')\" /></p>";
        } else { 
            doSubmit();
        }
    }
}

// curl
function curl($url, $post=false, $cookie=false) {
    global $ckfile;

    $curl_handle = curl_init();

    if($cookie == 'init') {
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if($post <> false) {
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post['data']);
    }

    $result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    return $result;
}

// craigslist
function craigs($url, $item = null, $pricemin = null, $pricemax = null)
{
    $i = 0;

    // http://ogden.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={item}&srchType=A&minAsk={pricemin}&maxAsk={pricemax}
    $result = curl("$url?query=$item&srchType=A&minAsk=$pricemin&maxAsk=$pricemax");

    if(strpos($result, 'Nothing found for that search') === false) {
        preg_match_all('/<p class="row">.*?<\/p>/is', $result, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

        $sevenDaysAgo = strtotime('8 days ago');
        $total = 0;

        foreach($output[0] as $out) {
                if($i < 100) {
                        preg_match_all('/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s*\d{1,2}/is', $out, $date, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

                        foreach($date[0] as $day) {
                                // Total count
                                $total++;

                                // Let's strip extra spaces...
                                $finalDay = preg_replace('/\s\s+/is', ' ', $day);

                                // Let's compare the dates...
                                if ($sevenDaysAgo < strtotime($finalDay)) {
                                        $i++;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    } else {
        // Nothing found.
    }

    return $i;
}

// ksl
function ksl($item = null, $zip = null, $distance = null, $pricemin = null, $pricemax = null)
{
    $i = 0;

    // http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=231&search=radio&zip=45174&distance=10&min_price=1&max_price=500&addisplay=%5BNOW-7DAYS+TO+NOW%5D&sort=5&nocache=1&viewNumResults=70&sort=5
    $result = curl("http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=231&search=$item&zip=$zip&distance=$distance&min_price=$pricemin&max_price=$pricemax&addisplay=%5BNOW-7DAYS+TO+NOW%5D&sort=5&nocache=1&viewNumResults=70&sort=5");

    if(strpos($result, 'There are no listings for this search.') === false) {
        preg_match_all('/<div class="adBox">.*?<\/div>/is', $result, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

        $i = count($output[0]);
    } else {
        // Nothing found.
    }

    return $i;
}

// house
function house($item = null, $type = 0, $city = null, $state = null, $zip = null, $distance = null, $seller = null, $pricemin = null, $pricemax = null, $minsqft = null, $maxsqft = null, $minacres = null, $maxacres = null, $minbed = null)
{
    // http://www.ksl.com/index.php?si=5017903&nid=651&city=Salt+Lake+City&zipcode=&distance=&state=&start=&end=25000&keyword=&sellertype=&acresstart=&acresend=&sqftstart=&sqftend=&bedrooms=&type=&homes_search=Search

    $done = false;
    $pid = 1;
    $i = 0;
    $sevenDaysAgo = strtotime('8 days ago');
    $total = 0;

    while(!$done) {
        $result = curl("http://www.ksl.com/index.php?sid=5017903&nid=651&city=$city&zipcode=$zip&distance=$distance&state=$state&start=$pricemin&end=$pricemax&keyword=$item&sellertype=$seller&acresstart=$minacres&acresend=$maxacres&sqftstart=$minsqft&sqftend=$maxsqft&bedrooms=$minbed&type=&homes_search=Search&pid=$pid");

        if(strpos($result, '0 results') === false) {
            preg_match_all('/<div class="postDate">.*?<\/div>/is', $result, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

            if(count($output[0] != 0)) {
                foreach($output[0] as $out) {
                    // Check the date on this entry.
                    preg_match_all('/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s*\d{1,2}/is', $out, $date, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
                    foreach($date[0] as $day) {
                        // Total count
                        $total++;
                        // Let's strip extra spaces...
                        $finalDay = preg_replace('/\s\s+/is', ' ', $day);
                        // Let's compare the dates...
                        if ($sevenDaysAgo < strtotime($finalDay)) {
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($i >= 70) {
                    $done = true;
                }

                $pid++;
            } else {
                $done = true;
            }
        } else {
            $done = true;
        }
    }

    return $i;
}

// car search
function car($pricemin, $pricemax, $vmake, $vmodel, $minmileage, $maxmileage, $year, $carseller, $doors)
{
    // Car values
    // $carMake = array(); - This is included in an external file.

    // $carModel = array(); - This is included in an external file.

    $carSeller = array(
                'dealer' => 288110,
                'owner' => 20);

    // Let's setup our post data:
    if(trim($vmake) <> "") {
        $fields['make'][$carMake[$vmake]] = 1;
    }

    if (trim($vmodel) <> "" && $vmodel <> 0) {
        $fields['model'][$carModel[$vmodel]] = 1;
    }

    if ($pricemin <> "") {
        $fields['sell_price'][$pricemin] = 1;
    }

    if ($pricemax <> "") {
        $fields['sell_price'][$pricemax] = 1;
    }

    if ($minmileage <> "") {
        $fields['mileage'][$minmileage] = 1;
    }

    if ($maxmileage <> "") {
        $fields['mileage'][$maxmileage] = 1;
    }

    if(is_array($doors)) {
        foreach($doors as $door) {
            $fields['doors'][$door] = 1;
        }
    }

    if(is_array($year)) {
        foreach($year as $yr) {
            $fields['year'][$yr] = 1;
        }
    }

    if(is_array($carseller)) {
        foreach($carseller as $seller) {
            if($seller == '' || $seller == ' ') { 
                $fields['seller_type']['0'] = 1;
            } else {
                $fields['seller_type'][$carSeller[$seller]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // We need to firstly initiate a cookie. This is done like so.
    curl('http://www.ksl.com/index.php?sid=0&nid=443', false, 'init');

    // Then, we need to set our search values. We can send a post value to do this.

    $data = 'call='.urlencode('save_query').'&sdata='.urlencode(urlencode(serialize($fields))).'&run='.urlencode('resources/community/java/community_rpc.php');

    $post['count'] = 3;
    $post['data'] = $data;

    // Submit our post data...


    $done = false;
    $pid = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $sevenDaysAgo = strtotime('8 days ago');

    while(!$done) {
        // do curl here
        $result = curl("http://www.ksl.com/index.php?sid=0&nid=443&tab=list&pid=$pid", false, true);
        $f = fopen('f.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($f, $result);
        fclose($f);

        if(strpos($result, 'There are no listings for this search.') === false) {
            preg_match_all('/<div class="adTime">.*?<\/div>/is', $result, $output, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

            if(count($output[0] != 0)) {
                foreach($output[0] as $out) {
                    // Check the date on this entry.
                    preg_match_all('/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s*\d{1,2}/is', $out, $date, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

                    foreach($date[0] as $day) {
                        // Let's strip extra spaces...
                        $finalDay = preg_replace('/\s\s+/is', ' ', $day);
                        // Let's compare the dates...
                        if ($sevenDaysAgo < strtotime($finalDay)) {
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($i >= 70) {
                    $done = true;
                }

                $pid++;
            } else {
                $done = true;
            }
        } else {
            $done = true;
            // Nothing found.
        }
    }

    return $i;
}

function doSubmit() {
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // This should trim any extra spaces in addition to any newlines or tabs.
    $_POST[$key] = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $value);
}

$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$pricemin=$_POST['pricemin'];
$pricemax=$_POST['pricemax'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];
$miles=$_POST['miles'];
$carsearch=$_POST['carsearch'];
$vmake=$_POST['vmake'];
$vmodel=$_POST['vmodel'];
$minmileage=$_POST['minmileage'];
$maxmileage=$_POST['maxmileage'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$carseller=$_POST['carseller'];
$doors=$_POST['doors'];
$homesearch=$_POST['homesearch'];
$propertytype=$_POST['propertytype'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$homeseller=$_POST['homeseller'];
$minacres=$_POST['minacres'];
$maxacres=$_POST['maxacres'];
$minsqfeet=$_POST['minsqfeet'];
$maxsqfeet=$_POST['maxsqfeet'];
$minbedrooms=$_POST['minbedrooms'];
$maxbedrooms=$_POST['maxbedrooms'];



// check email & phone validity
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email) && !preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $phone)) {
    die();
}
$url="id.txt";
$id=file($url);
$next=$id[0]+1;


$fp=fopen("form$next.txt", "a");
$fh=fopen($url, 'w') or die ("cant open file");
$savestring =  $carsearch . "\n" . $homesearch . "\n" . $next . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $item . "\n" . $pricemin . "\n" . $pricemax . "\n"  . $zip . "\n"   . $miles . "\n"   . $vmake . "\n"  . $vmodel . "\n"  . $minmileage . "\n" . $maxmileage . "\n"  . implode(",",$_POST['year']) . "\n" . implode(",",$_POST['carseller']) . "\n" . implode(",",$_POST['doors']) . "\n"  . $propertytype . "\n"  . $city . "\n"  . $state . "\n"  . $homeseller . "\n"  . $minacres . "\n"  . $maxacres . "\n"  . $minsqfeet . "\n"  . $maxsqfeet . "\n"  . $minbedrooms . "\n"  . $maxbedrooms . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
unlink("id.txt");
$fa=fopen("id.txt", "a");
fwrite($fa, $next);
fclose($fa)


//header("Location:http://www.mywebsite.com/formsubmit.html");
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location = \"http://www.mywebsite.com/formsubmit.html"\"</script";
}

unlink($ckfile);
?>
```

Its a lot to look at, but I am just totally stumped at this point.  Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Look at the error message in your webserver's error log. It probably tells you exactly what is going on. There's no sense in us guessing a thousand things.

Comment: Further to the above, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` above the require statements in case you don't have access to the logs.

Comment: I checked the error log and found this

Comment: [20-Apr-2012 12:28:22] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/func2.php on line 133

Comment: $words = explode(" ", $_POST['item']) is missing a semi colon at the end.

Comment: so I took out the unexpected { and now the error log says

Comment: [20-Apr-2012 13:09:23] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home6/mywebsite/public_html/func2.php on line 134

Comment: Your file contains a lot of errors if you just started checking it right now. Go over all the errors and fix them. There is no point posting each and everyone of them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
    $words = explode(" ", $_POST['item']) {
```

Should be

```
    $words = explode(" ", $_POST['item']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add semi-colons. :)

```
<?php
  include('db.php')
  include('func.php')
?>
```

should become

```
<?php
  include('db.php');
  include('func.php');
?>
```

Comment: oh, yeah I have the semicolons, I just forgot to type them on this

Comment: hehe, good point.  I will close the thread.  I just needed to look at the error log.  You guys helped me a lot.  I really appreciate this.